# On the excerpt of `linux` tag, why is running Linux distros on Android off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Just found the [linux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag and the excerpt said:

> [...] (Note that running Linux distros on Android is off-topic.) [...]

I can't grasp the reason for that, especially from the name of the community.

Answer (score 4):

[Chenmunka's answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2672/44325) already gave the correct reasoning:

> If you are running a variety of Linux on your hardware, then you are almost certainly not running Android.

However, questions regarding the installation of Linux-based OS on Android devices are *still* on-topic (e.g. Linux Deploy). It is when the questions are about *operating* them, that's where the questions are off-topic because it is not about Android anymore, and the community lacks expertise about it.

As such, I've updated the excerpt to

> Note that questions purely about operating Linux-based OS on Android devices are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

The wording could be improved.  It would be clearer if it said something like:

> Questions regarding replacing Android with Linux distros are
> off-topic.

If you are running a variety of Linux on your hardware, then you are almost certainly not running Android.

This site is for Android, so putting Android onto a Linux box is on-topic, but not the other way around.

Comment: I think I quite agree although I disagree

Comment: You proclaim this, but has this been established as true? If so, it would be a good place to link to that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

there are no linux "distros" one can install on any smartphone. linux has to be build especially for that device, like custom ROM and any other firmware for embedded devices - and therefore on top of android kernel. have a look into Ubuntu touch you will notice it is just a `chroot` on android.

questions are better placed on Android Enthusiasts than on the Unix & Linux site.

[https://www.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch-next-generation-os-or-just-another-skin](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507043024/https://www.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch-next-generation-os-or-just-another-skin)